# I want query to count duplicate entries from 3 separate columns in a table bu with same data type (C#)

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, union

i am having syntax error with the following sql statement 
the thing is i wan to count duplicate in 3 differents columns in a table.
i am using visual studio 2010 and .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB

this query will return all entry in one recordset

```
string testqry = 
SELECT NO_IDENT_1 As NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
Union All 
SELECT NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
Union All 
SELECT NO_IDENT_3 As NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25});
```

but the following will signal syntax error

```
    string RqNbIdent10 =
"SELECT COUNT(*) as repeat 
from ( 
    SELECT NO_IDENT_1 As NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25})     
    Union All 
    SELECT NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
    Union All 
    SELECT NO_IDENT_3 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
    ) GROUP BY NO_IDENT_2"
```

Comment: What SQL version are you using? and what is the exact error message

Comment: i am using visual studio 2010 and .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB

Comment: This is the sort of thing best done with a PIVOT table perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the sub-select result set, here I have identified as results.

```
SELECT results.NO_IDENT_2, COUNT(results.NO_IDENT_2) as repeat 
from ( 
    SELECT NO_IDENT_1 As NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25})     
    Union All 
    SELECT NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
    Union All 
    SELECT NO_IDENT_3 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
    ) results GROUP BY results.NO_IDENT_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `SELECT NO_IDENT_3 FROM P240538` to this:

`SELECT NO_IDENT_3 AS NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538`

Comment: That wont make any difference to the result set, the columns of which are defined by the select specification of the first union only.

Comment: I thought all the column names have to be the same in a UNION operation.

Comment: No, they just to have the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT xx.No_Ident_2,COUNT(*) as repeat 
    from ( 
        SELECT NO_IDENT_1 As NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25})     
        Union All 
        SELECT NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
        Union All 
        SELECT NO_IDENT_3 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/25}) 
        ) xx
        GROUP BY xx.NO_IDENT_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ALL from the "UNION ALL".

UPDATE: sorry, I misread. You actually want to select the duplicates. Or the records for which a duplicate exists.

Comment: I think you are guessing. He needs the rows repeated because he's selecting a different column in each set. The ALL in no way affects the syntactic correctness of the statement.

Comment: I wasn't referring to syntax, only semantics. The underlying problem is the violation of the 1NF.